# How would I split a substring into multiple chunks and enter them into a table using C#?

Tags: split, substring

I am in need of taking a line like the following and splitting it into at least 2 chunks (one chunk being of 4 numbers and the other chunk being of just 1)

There are 3 different sets of information I need to enter into the table that is

group number - 5 digit number 
code - 4 digit number
indicator - 1 digit number

**Example in File**
56743        **4888**1**4988**1**3242**2**8759**7**4876**1

I would need to iterate through the substring that includes the code and indicator until it is fully read... can be up to 12 occurances of 4

the final product in the table would be something like the following:

56743        4888          1 
56743        4988          1 
56743        3242          2

and so forth.  Any help would be appreciated.  I should note that I am aware of how I would go about entering it into the table, its the actual retrieving the info that is stumping me, particularly due to the up to 12 thing

Comment: is white space part of your string always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
var splitedCode = new List<int>();
string value = "56743 4888149881324228759748761";
string pref = value.Split(' ')[0];
string reMainValue = value.Split(' ')[1];
while (reMainValue.Length > 0)
{
      int subStrLength = reMainValue.Length > 5 ? 5 : reMainValue.Length;
      splitedCode.Add(int.Parse(reMainValue.Substring(0, subStrLength)));
      reMainValue = reMainValue.Substring(subStrLength);
}
foreach (var item in splitedCode)
{
      Console.WriteLine(pref + " " + item.ToString("#### #"));
}
Console.ReadLine();
```